# Python: problema com lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alguém saberia explicar e como corrigir o porque ocorre o problema na saida abaixo quando uso números repetidos? Obrigado!
O retorno deve ser apresentado na forma inversa e sem apresentar o "0"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    lista = []

n = int(input("Digite um número: "))
while n != 0:
    lista.append(n)
    n = int(input("Digite um número: "))
    if n == 0:
        lista.append(n)

i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    if len(lista) <= 1:
        break
    lista.remove(lista[-1])
    print(lista[-1])
```

Comment: O que é suposto acontecer? Aqui parece estar a funcionar bem... Retorna na ordem inversa

Comment: Atente para o numero "5" ele muda de ordem, se pores um print(lista) pode ficar melhor a visualização.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192304/invertendo-sequ%c3%aancia-python-3/463887#463887)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
...
lista.remove(lista[-1])
...
```

Deve-se ao facto do `remove()` remover a primeira ocorrência do elemento, ou seja, para os inputs, "`2,2,5,2`", obtive:

> 2
>  2
>  2
>  5

Na primeira volta aparentemente estás a eliminar o ultimo elemento: `remove(lista[-1])`, que neste caso fica `remove(2)`, MAS, este 2 que vai ser removido vai ser o primeiro e não o ultimo:

**`remove(x)`**

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x.

Tradução

> Remove o primeiro item da lista cujo valor é x.

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Ou seja o que vai acontecer à tua lista ao longo do teu segundo loop `while` é:

> [2, 2, 5, 2, 0]
>  [2, 2, 5, 2]
>  [2, 5, 2]
>  [5, 2]
>  [5]

E os prints da  `lista[-1]` que neste caso vão ser:

> 2
> 2
> 2
> 5

(não esquecer que o 0 foi eliminado antes do primeiro print)

Se me permites vou apresentar uma sugestão de melhoria (para fazer exatamente isto) sem modificar muito o teu código:

```
lista = []
n = int(input("Digite um número: "))
while n != 0:
    lista.append(n)
    n = int(input("Digite um número: "))

while lista: # enquanto houverem elementos na lista, equivalente a while len(lista) > 0
    ele = lista.pop() # retirar o ultimo elemento da lista
    print(ele)
```

[DOCS DE pop()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Ou se preferires eliminas na mesma pelo index:

```
lista = []
n = int(input("Digite um número: "))
while n != 0:
    lista.append(n)
    n = int(input("Digite um número: "))

while lista: # enquanto houverem elementos na lista, equivalente a while len(lista) > 0
    ele = lista[-1]
    del lista[len(lista)-1]
    print(ele)
```

E até podemos ir mais longe, se o objetivo for só imprimir e retirar os inputs que estão na lista em ordem inversa podemos eliminar o segundo while e tiramos os casts para int:

```
lista = []
n = input("Digite um número: ")
while n != '0':
    lista.append(n)
    n = input("Digite um número: ")

print('\n'.join(reversed(lista)))
lista.clear()
```

Comment: Excelente Miguel! Desconhecia o "pop", ele resolve perfeitamente o meu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Sim mas também podes ir removendo por indexes @MárioAntônioRodeghiero , vou fazer para veres, 5 mins. Mas o importante é perceberes o porquê do que estava a acontecer. De nada, boa noite

Comment: Tranquilo, quando tiver tempo é só postar! Valeu a força, devo aparecer com mais duvidas esta semana. vlw!