# Invertendo sequência (PYTHON 3)

Tags: python

Tenho que implementar o seguinte:

Escreva um programa que recebe uma sequência de números inteiros terminados por 0 e imprima todos os valores em ordem inversa. **Note que 0 (ZERO) não deve fazer parte da sequência.

Exemplo:

```
Digite um número: 1
Digite um número: 7
Digite um número: 4
Digite um número: 0

4
7
1
```

Fiz o seguinte código, mas não consigo restringir o 0.

```
seq = []
i = 1

while i > 0:
    n = int(input("Digite n: "))    
    seq.append(n)

    while n == 0:

        for i in seq[i]:

            print (i)
            i -= 0
```

Alguém poderia me dizer o que fiz de errado???

Answer (score 12):

Se você quer ter um estilo Pythonico de programar, pode fazer assim:

Para ler os dados pode considerar o exemplo do nosso amigo Arcashaid. Seguindo com a parte de inverter a lista, veja como é elegante no estilo pythonico:

```
seq.reverse()
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
seq = seq[::-1]
```

Comment: Obrigado Andrey.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que ambos os métodos criam uma nova lista na memória e, se `seq` for muito grande, pode trazer prejuízos à aplicação, enquanto utilizar a função `reversed` cria um *generator*, consumindo pouca memória independente do tamanho da lista.

Comment: Muito bem colocado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 7):

Problemas:

1. O trecho `while n == 0` produzirá um loop infinito e assim irá imprimir infinitamente números na tela (não queremos isso).
2. O valor `seq[i]` será um valor inteiro e portanto não é iterável; fazer `for i in seq[i]` não faz sentido algum.

Uma dica: para aprender Python *da forma pythonica* você precisará se livrar de qualquer vício de programação que você talvez tenha com outras linguagens.

Eu resolveria seu problema assim:

```
# Lista de valores:
seq = []

# Executa até ocorrer `break`
while True:

    # Pede ao usuário um valor inteiro:
    n = int(input("Digite n: "))    

    # Se for zero, pare o loop:
    if n == 0: break

    # Se não, adiciona o valor a lista:
    seq.append(n)

# Percorre toda a lista de trás para frente:
for i in reversed(seq):

    # Exibe o valor na tela:
    print(i)
```

Com um loop infinito você lê os valores até encontrar zero, enquanto isso adiciona-os à lista. Ao final, percorre toda a lista de trás para frente, com a função `reversed`, exibindo os valores.

Você pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/Gb3o/0).

---

Na versão 3.8 do Python foi adicionado a [*assignment expression*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/5878) que permitiria simplificar o código acima, que gera uma lista de valores a partir da entrada enquanto não for informado o número 0:

```py
seq = []

while (n := int(input('Digite n: '))) != 0:
    seq.append(n)
```

A lista `seq` possuirá todos os números informados enquanto não for informado o valor 0. Só um cuidado deve ser tomado quanto à validação da entrada, pois a estrutura `int` lança uma exceção `ValueError` se o valor informado não for numérico; a exceção não está sendo tratada no exemplo.

Comment: Valeu pelos esclarecimentos. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

```
seq = []
while True:
    numero = int(input())
    if (numero != 0):
        seq.append(numero)
    else:
        break

for i in seq[::-1]:
    print (i)
```

Eu fiz desse modo por que gosto de utilizar while com breaks, mas teria como fazer na mesma condição do while, espero ter entendido direito o que vc queri, se não for isso avise-me que eu modifico a resposta

Comment: Valeu pela resposta ficou muito bom mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
def numReverse(n,numInv = 0):
  while n > 0:
    resto = n % 10
    n = n // 10
    numInv = numInv * 10 + resto
  print(numInv)
```

exemplo usa

```
numReverse(123)
numReverse(918273563)
```

Answer (score 0):

O código permanece no loop enquanto n é diferente de zero, sai quando n=0 e não adiciona o zero à lista. Segue o código

```
seq = []
#inicia n com 1 para entrar no loop
n = 1

while n:
    n = int(input("Digite n: "))
    # só adiciona na lista se for diferente de zero
    if n!=0 : seq.append(n)
print(seq)
# para inverter uma lista, é só usar [::-1]
print(seq[::-1])
```

A saída ficou:

```
Digite n: 1
Digite n: 2
Digite n: 3
Digite n: 4
Digite n: 5
Digite n: 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, o número **0** não será contabilizado e nem inserido na lista. Neste caso, o **0** funcionará apenas como `flag` de parada, ou seja, quando for digitado o valor `"0"`, o fluxo normal do programa será encerrado. A partir deste momento, o programa exibirá todos os valores digitados anteriormente em ordem inversa, **exceto** o valor "0".

Para resolver esta questão pode ser utilizado o seguinte código:

```
lista = list()
while True:
    n = int(input(f'Digite um número: '))

    if n != 0:
        lista.append(n)
    else:
        cont = 0
        while len(lista) >= 1:
            print(lista[-1])
            del(lista[-1])
            cont -= 1
        break
```

Observe que, ao ser digitado um valor, o programa verifica se o mesmo é `diferente` de "0". Se for diferente de "0", o referido valor será inserido em **lista** e o `laço de repetição` - que alimenta a lista - será reiniciado. Caso contrário, o laço de repetição será encerrado e a lista será exibida em ordem inversa sem o valor "0".

Observe também que, quem controla a `exibição` dos elementos da lista é o 2º while. Para isso, ele verifica se o tamanho da lista é maior ou igual a `"1"`. Caso seja, é exibido o último elemento da lista `(lista[-1])`. Depois, deleta o referido elemento da lista e decrementa o contador. Em seguida, todo esse processo é refeito até a lista inicial não possuir mais elementos.

Outra forma de resolver esta questão seria:

```
lista = list()
while True:
    n = int(input(f'Digite um número: '))

    if n != 0:
        lista.append(n)
    else:
        for c in sorted(lista, reverse=True):
            print(c)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

#inverter apenas um numeros

```
n = input("Digite um número:")
print (''.join(reversed(n)))
```

#inverter letras (de uma palavra)

```
n = input("Digite uma Palavra:")
print (''.join(reversed(n)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
retorne = input("Digite seu número: ") 

def InverterNum():
    reverter =[]
    reverter.extend(retorne)
    reverter.reverse()

    revertido = str(reverter).strip('[]')
    revertido = ''.join(reverter)

    return revertido

ver = print("Seu número invertido: " + InverterNum())
```