# O que são Assignment Expressions do Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As *assignment expressions* estão definidas na [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) que foi aprovada para ser implementada na versão 3.8 do Python.

- Mas o que são as *assignment expressions* e quando deverão ser utilizadas?
- Que tipo de problema sua implementação busca resolver?
- Por que sua implementação causou polêmica na comunidade Python? Ela vai contra os "princípios" da linguagem?

Comment: suponho que você mesmo esteja elaborando uma reposta bem legal aí -

Comment: @jsbueno de certa forma, mas sinta-se convidado a responder também.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A resposta vai por níveis.

- Conceito simples:
- Conceito completo:
- Exemplo:
- Como usar:
- Referencias:

---

### Conceito simples:

Podemos dizer de forma " "simples" " que é definir uma variável e passá-la como valor ao mesmo tempo.

Ex.:

```
# $ entrada do código 
# > saída do código 

$ a = 1
>
$ a
> 1
```

Então o que você pode passar a fazer é juntar as duas coisas em uma única linha. Ficando assim:

```
$ a := 1    # Você definiu a variável e ao mesmo tempo ela passa o valor adiante.
> 1
```

---

### Conceito completo:

#### Abstract:

É uma proposta para definir variáveis como uma expressão.( NAME **:=** expr )

- adicionada uma nova exceção "TargetScopeError".

#### Motivação:

Nomear o resultado de uma expressão é uma parte importante da programação, assim permitindo ser usado no lugar de uma longa expressão e permitindo o reúso.

```
...
a = foo(x)
baa(a)
cee(a)
...
```

Agora pode ser :

```
...
baa(a:=foo(x))
cee(a)
...
```

#### A real importância:

Não vou citar directamente aqui pois é grande e é bom que se leia tudo, o link está no fim da resposta. Se alguém quiser eu resumo e altero aqui.
E sim teve discussões se isso é pythônico.

#### Sintaxe:

Muitos contextos arbitrários em que expressões Python podem ser usadas. Isto é a forma de NAME := expr onde a expr é uma expressão Python válida como uma tupla sem parênteses e NAME é o identificador.

```
$ a = 3,1
$ type(a)
> <class 'tuple'>
```

**regex**

```
if (match := pattern.search(data)) is not None:
    # Do something with match
```

**Loop não pode ser facilmente reescrito usando 2 argumentos iterativos.**

```
while chunk := file.read(8192):
   process(chunk)
```

***Analizar valor é caro computacionalmente***

```
[y := f(x), y**2, y**3]
```

**Compartilha a sub-expressão entre um filtro e uma "saída".**

```
filtered_data = [y for x in data if (y := f(x)) is not None]
```

#### Casos excepcionais: (Inválidos e válidos porem não recomendados.)

Amanhã posto com calma, por causa do meu horário, porém tem no link  referencia do PEP 572 no final da resposta. :)
Se for usar recomendo a leitura.

---

### Exemplo:

Caso alguém queira, crio um exemplo mais complexo, porém vou deixar um que achei bem simples porem demostrativo que está na própria PEP.

```
# Computar uma lista de somas parciais e retornar o total
total = 0
partial_sums = [total := total + v for v in values]
print("Total:", total)

# Legal né :)
```

---

### Referência:

[PEP 572 -- Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

[Exemplo de uso - VIDEO - EN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh99F05BOMU)