# Atribuição em teste condicional no PHP

Tags: php, variáveis, condição

Estou estudando PHP e me deparei com uma *feature* que não existe no Python (não sei em outras linguagens), que é a atribuição num teste condicional:

```
$file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "w");
while($row = fgets($file)){
    ...
}
```

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado mas num teste condicional, o mesmo busca verificar o resultado da condição ou o estado do objeto por exemplo uma lista vazia é `false`, isso que chamamos de *Truthy* e *Falsey* em Javascript. Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Essa *feature* existe somente em PHP?
2. Como funciona isso por debaixo dos panos?

Comment: [O que são Assignment Expressions do Python 3.8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/5878)

Comment: Isso é uma atribuição inline, nao tem nada a ver com o condicional. Veja um exemplo: `$a = 30 + ($b = 10) * 5;` https://ideone.com/OOOxds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Essa feature existe somente em PHP?

Não, ela existe em praticamente todas as linguagens, e até em Python com alguma restrição (pelo menos em versão atual)

> Como funciona isso por debaixo dos panos?

Não tem nada demais, isto é só questão sintática, é só o compilador deixar escrever assim, a execução será igual à forma não *inline*.

Em Assembly cada instrução (bem básica) vai em uma linha, linguagens de alto nível permutem colocar várias delas na mesma linha, o quanto isto é permitido é decisão de cada linguagem. Por baixo do pano mesmo isto envolve uma enorme "desabstração", mas sem querer fazer isto a fundo podemos entender assim (note que o próprio `while` é uma abstração):

```
inicio:
    $row = fgets($file);
    if (!$row) goto fim;
    ...
    goto inicio;
fim:
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/WhileInternal.php).

Comment: Interessante Maniero.  Isso seria, teoricamente, o que ocorre "debaixo dos panos" em um while? Tipo.. (análise da condição naquele instante) ... Se for verdade volta para o inicio, se não, vá para o fim... Desculpa a minha ignorância. =)

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Comment: Eu tenho muito o que estudar... XD

Comment: Mas tem a curiosidade e isto já ajuda muito, se precisar faça mais perguntas úteis como esta.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Não, na verdade ele é uma ordem de magnitude mais lenta, interprete os resultados direito. Na verdade os resultados são inconsistentes e o mais lento foi o `goto`, provavelmente porque as outra formas fazem otimizações.

Comment: Entendi Maniero. Obrigado. Vou verificar melhor. De qualquer forma obrigado pelo incentivo e atenção.

Comment: Verdade! Viajei no código! kkkkk Valeu!