# Definição formal das operações = e ==

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminologia, operadores

Qual a definição formal sobre o uso de `=` e de `==` no Python? Consigo identificar nos exemplos quando tenho que usar qual, mas quando tento identificar essas operações por uma definição formal como (mais ou menos como se fosse um conceito matemático) me enrolo.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 8):

É muito simples, o `=` é um **operador de atribuição**, você só deve usá-lo para guardar um valor em uma variável. O operando do lado esquerdo sempre deve ser uma variável, nada mais que isto. Já o operando direito aceita um valor vindo de uma literal, uma variável (outra ou a mesma, ainda que não faça muito sentido ser a mesma) ou uma expressão que será executada e o seu resultado gerará um valor, e o valor final obtido será guardado na variável.

O `==` é um **operador de comparação**. Os dois lados podem ser variáveis, literais ou expressões diversas. Sempre tentará identificar que o valor final obtido do lado esquerdo é igual ao valor final obtido no lado direito. O resultado da operação de comparação será do tipo booleano, ou seja, será `True` ou `False`. É muito comum usá-lo um um `if` ou `while`, mas não precisa ser assim, pode ser usado em qualquer lugar que espera um booleano, inclusive pode ser usando no lado direito do `=` e atribuir esse valor à uma variável ou pode usar para imprimir algo ou passar como argumento em uma função.

O conceito é válido para essencialmente qualquer linguagem.

```
x = 1 == 2
```

Este é um exemplo onde `x` valerá `False` porque está atribuindo na variável o que está do lado direito que é uma comparação se são valores iguais, o que obviamente não são. Para entender um pouco melhor podemos fazer isso, ainda que desnecessário pela precedência a associatividade de operadores:

```
x = (1 == 2)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/AssignAndEquals.py).

Answer (score 4):

Bem, não consigo imaginar uma definição mais formal do que a própria [documentação oficial da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html). Então vamos a ela:

---

## *Assignment Statements*

O `=` é chamado de [*assignment statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) (declaração de atribuição), cuja definição é:

> *Assignment statements are used to (re)bind names to values and to modify attributes or items of mutable objects*

Ou seja, ele serve para vincular (ou revincular) nomes a seus respectivos valores, e também para modificar atributos de objetos mutáveis.

Tecnicamente falando, o `=` é apenas **uma parte** do *assignment statement*, já que este é composto também das partes que vêm antes e depois do `=`:

```py
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

Não vou listar todas as possibilidades, mas apenas para dar alguns exemplos:

```py
# atribuir um valor a uma variável
x = 1
# atribuir um valor a várias variáveis de uma vez
x = y = z = 1

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# mudar valor de uma posição da lista
lista[2] = 10
# slice, muda um pedaço da lista
lista[1:4] = [ 8 ]
print(lista) # [1, 8, 5]

dic = { 'nome': 'Fulano', 'idade': 42 }
# mudar o valor da chave de um dicionário
dic['nome'] = 'Ciclano'
# ou, adicionar uma nova chave
dic['email'] = 'ciclano@mail.com'
print(dic) # {'nome': 'Ciclano', 'idade': 42, 'email': 'ciclano@mail.com'}

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# x recebe 1, y recebe 2, resto recebe o restante da lista [3, 4, 5]
x, y, *resto = lista

x = 1
y = 2
# troca os valores de x e y
x, y = y, x
```

Lembrando que o lado direito de uma atribuição pode ser qualquer expressão válida que seja compatível com o lado esquerdo (por exemplo, em `x, y = lista`, a lista deve ter pelo menos dois elementos, senão dará erro).

Vale lembrar também que **o `=` não é um operador** (*em algumas linguagens é, mas em Python não*), tanto que no Python 3.8 foi criada a [*Assignment Expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) (ver também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/112052)), que define o operador `:=` e possui [algumas diferenças com relação a `=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements) (basta ver que a [Tabela de Precedência de Operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) tem o `:=`, mas não tem o `=`).

---

## Comparador de igualdade

O `==` é um dos [operadores de comparação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), que no caso verifica se os valores dos operandos são iguais.

Lembrando que o [*Data Model*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects) da linguagem define o "valor" de um objeto de maneira bem abstrata, pois depende muito dos tipos envolvidos. Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) estão descritas todas as regras para os tipos nativos - por exemplo, números em geral podem ser comparados entre tipos diferentes (um `int` e um `float` podem ser iguais), já para sequências (como listas e tuplas) [a regra é diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/549346/112052), etc.

Por fim, qualquer classe que você criar pode sobrescrever o [método `__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) e definir seu próprio algoritmo para determinar se dois objetos são iguais. Basicamente, ao fazer `x == y`, será feita a chamada a `x.__eq__(y)`. Se você não sobrescrever este método, ele chama a implementação de `object`, que usa o [operador `is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) (que considera dois objetos iguais somente se eles forem o mesmo objeto).

Um detalhe importante é que o operador `==` sempre retorna um *booleano* (`True` ou `False`), mas o método `__eq__` pode retornar qualquer valor (que por sua vez, se for usado em um contexto *booleano*, será convertido usando-se `bool()`):

> *By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an `if` statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.*

---

Portanto, são coisas bem diferentes. Uma forma didática de pensar é:

- `nome = algo` está **dizendo** ao Python que `nome` recebe o valor `algo` - é uma afirmação (ou se preferir, uma ordem: "coloque o valor `algo` na variável `nome`")
- `nome == algo` está **perguntando** ao Python se o valor de `nome` é `algo` - e a resposta será sim ou não (`True` ou `False`, que é o resultado da expressão)

Answer (score 2):

> "=" Faz a atribuiçao.
>
> "==" Faz a comparação.