# Por que comparações entre tipos diferentes dá True em alguns casos e False em outros, mesmo com os valores sendo iguais em ambos os casos?

Tags: python, tipagem, comparação

Me deparei com seguinte situação:

```
print(0 == 0.0) # True
```

Acabei investigando e encontrei [este link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp).

Entendi que tem a ver com o *data type*, já que ambos são *numeric types*. Se compara-se os tipos de cada entrada (`type(0.0) == type(0)`) o retorno seria `False`, por isso interpretei que o *data type* que explicaria essa condição de `True`.

Se eu tento fazer a mesma coisa com *sequence types* não funciona. Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo?

```
print(['oi', 'oi'] == ('oi', 'oi')) # False
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Complementando as respostas, o artigo citado na pergunta é bem fraquinho (pra não dizer outra coisa, aliás é por isso que não leio mais aquele site, achei que tinha melhorado mas pelo jeito não) e eu consideraria mudar as fontes de estudo (a documentação oficial que eu linkei abaixo, por exemplo, é bem melhor). Enfim, o problema não é o tipo em si, e sim a forma como cada tipo implementa a operação de igualdade (como já explicado abaixo). O artigo em si não tem relação direta com este comportamento.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem um caminhão carregando duas mesas e um carro carregando duas mesas idênticas, você considera que as duas situações são a mesma coisa?

Quando compara uma lista (delimitado por colchetes) com uma tupla (delimitado por parênteses) nem precisa olhar o que tem dentro, já é diferente.

Você não perguntou mas vou dizer. Se tiver um caminhão com duas mesas dentro e outro caminhão com duas mesas idênticas, você acha que são iguais?

Aqui complica um pouco. Só é observado os caminhões, não considera o que tem dentro. E não sabendo o que tem dentro é melhor considerar que é diferente. Isto ocorre nos chamados [tipos por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/464539/101). É potencialmente muito caro  verificar tudo o que tem dentro para certificar que é igual ou não.

Mas é pior, a tupla tem semântica de tipo por valor e espera-se que ela seja curta, ao contrário da lista que espera-se que seja grande, então a linguagem olha o que tem dentro para saber se é igual. Percebe que fica complicado verificar igualdade com uma coisa que não olha dentro com outra que olha?

E agora se for verificar se uma mesa é igual a outra que são idênticas, ainda que de marcas diferentes (provavelmente porque é ORM vindo da China), as mesas são iguais?

Agora estou falando do primeiro exemplo que é um tipo com semântica de valor, então você pode ver facilmente o que tem ali e vê que é igual, apesar do detalhe da etiqueta.

> Entendi que tem a ver com o *data type*, já que ambos são *numeric types*. Se compara-se os tipos de cada entrada (`type(0.0) == type(0)`) o retorno seria `False`, por isso interpretei que o *data type* que explicaria essa condição de `True`.

Esse parágrafo não faz sentido.

Quase todas as linguagens decidiram que todos os tipos numéricos básicos são universalizados e você pode operar baseado no valor sem a preocupação com o seu tipo, afinal na matemática não existe essa diferenciação de tipos, portanto se a linguagem diferenciar estaria subvertendo a matemática. É mais intuitivo assim.

Então você tem que ler toda documentação para saber como todos os tipos se comportam. Nela tem informação da equivalência dos tipos numéricos ou outras possíveis equivalências. É a única forma de entender certo como cada situação se comporta.

Por isso a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/) é fundamental, não fontes secundárias que podem ou não estarem certas ou completas (muitas tecnologias até a oficial tem erros). Não "ache", procure fontes confiáveis sempre. Não só na programação. "Achando" é que se cria *fake news*.

Comment: Aproveitando a deixa da sua metáfora, dá pra dizer que os caminhões são diferentes porque têm números de chassi diferentes. Mesmo se a carga fosse idêntica.

Answer (score 2):

> *Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo?*

## Resposta curta

É assim porque a linguagem definiu que é assim :-)

## Resposta longa

Na documentação oficial da linguagem [tem uma seção inteira](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) dando mais detalhes sobre como essas comparações são feitas.

Sobre as comparações entre números:

> *Numbers of built-in numeric types ([Numeric Types — `int`, `float`, `complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric)) and of the standard library types `fractions.Fraction` and `decimal.Decimal` **can be compared within and across their types**, with the restriction that complex numbers do not support order comparison. Within the limits of the types involved, they compare mathematically (algorithmically) correct without loss of precision.*

O ponto-chave aqui é o trecho "*can be compared within and across their types*". Isso quer dizer que um `int` pode ser comparado com outros tipos numéricos (como por exemplo um `float`) sem problemas, por isso que `0` e `0.0` são iguais (pois segundo o trecho acima, "*a comparação é matematicamente correta sem perda de precisão*").

Existe também [outro ponto da documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id2) que complementa:

> *Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the "narrower" type is widened to that of the other, where integer is narrower than floating point, which is narrower than complex. **A comparison between numbers of different types behaves as though the exact values of those numbers were being compared**.*

Enfim, é por isso que um `int` com valor `0` é igual a um `float` com valor `0.0`.

---

Já sobre a comparação entre uma lista e uma tupla, temos o seguinte:

> *Sequences (instances of `tuple`, `list`, or `range`) **can be compared only within each of their types**, with the restriction that ranges do not support order comparison. **Equality comparison across these types results in inequality**, and ordering comparison across these types raises TypeError.*
>
> ...
>
> *Lexicographical comparison between built-in collections works as follows:*
>
> - *For two collections to compare equal, **they must be of the same type**, have the same length, and each pair of corresponding elements must compare equal (**for example, `[1,2] == (1,2)` is false because the type is not the same**).*

Ou seja, qualquer comparação feita entre tipos diferentes de sequências (por exemplo, comparar uma lista com uma tupla) terá como resultado `False` (mesmo que os elementos dentro delas sejam iguais), pois um dos critérios para determinar a igualdade é que ambos os operandos tenham o mesmo tipo.

Em [outro ponto da documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) também há um parágrafo que basicamente confirma esta informação:

> *...to compare equal, every element must compare equal and **the two sequences must be of the same type** and have the same length*

É por isso que o resultado de `['oi', 'oi'] == ('oi', 'oi')` é `False`, pois apesar de terem os mesmos elementos, os tipos das sequências são diferentes (um é uma lista, outro é uma tupla).