# Exibir menor, média e maior até uma linha vazia ser digitada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
qtdNumeros = int(input())
if qtdNumeros <= 0:
    menor = "Nenhum"
    media = "Nenhuma"
    maior = "Nenhum"
else:
    menor = maior = soma = float(input())
    for proximo in range(1, qtdNumeros):
        valor = float(input())
        soma += valor
        if valor < menor:
            menor = valor
        elif valor > maior:
            maior = valor
    media = soma / qtdNumeros
print("Menor Lido:", menor)
print("Média dos Lidos:", media)
print("Maior Lido:", maior)
```

Gostaria de implementar o seguinte:
Ao invés de eu passar uma quantidade de entrada, eu inserir entrada até que uma linha vazia seja digitada e ai ele processar e exibir o menor, a media e o maior e, ao invés de digitar um número negativo, digitar somente uma linha vazia.
Poderiam me ajudar? Como iniciante não estou conseguindo :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python já possui funções prontas para identificar o menor e o maior valor de uma lista, bem como calcular a média da mesma.

- Para identificar o menor valor: `min`
- Para identificar o maior valor: `max`
- Para calcular a média: `statistics.mean`

Assim, basta criarmos um laço de repetição infinito, pois não sabemos quantos números serão informados e interrompemos o laço quando uma linha vazia for recebida.

```py
from statistics import mean

numbers = []

while True:
    number = input()

    if number == '':
        break

    numbers.append(float(number))

print('O menor valor informado foi', min(numbers))
print('O maior valor informado foi', max(numbers))
print('A média dos valores foi', mean(numbers))
```

Com Python 3.8, utilizando o *walrus operator* (por vezes citado em português como operador morsa - porque aparentemente o `:=` lembra as presas de uma morsa) , você pode fazer o laço de repetição como segue:

```py
from statistics import mean

numbers = []

while (number := input()) != '':
    numbers.append(float(number))

print('O menor valor informado foi', min(numbers))
print('O maior valor informado foi', max(numbers))
print('A média dos valores foi', mean(numbers))
```

- [O que são Assignment Expressions do Python 3.8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/5878)

E, caso não puder utilizar as funções `min`, `max` e `mean` para resolver o problema, basta você iterar sobre a sua lista e aplicar as condições necessárias.

- Para identificar o menor valor, comece assumindo que o primeiro valor da lista é o menor valor, percorra a lista inteira e para cada valor compare com o menor valor atual; se for menor, atualize o valor deste;
- Para identificar o maior valor, comece assumindo que o primeiro valor da lista é o maior valor, percorra a lista inteira e para cada valor compare com o maior valor atual; se for maior, atualize o valor deste;
- Para calcular a média, como esperado, basta calcular a soma de todos os valores e dividir pela quantidade;

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações no código e coloquei alguns blocos `try`/`except` porque no código da pergunta não existia validação e quando se passava um valor diferente do esperado o código dava erro. No entanto, no segundo `try`/`except`, coloquei um `if` para não exibir a mensagem em caso de saída da execução.

Coloquei um primeiro `while` para só aceitar o primeiro valor quando fosse realmente válido.

Depois removi o `for` que existia e o troquei por um `while` verificando se o valor de entrada era igual a uma string vazia, assim não seria necessário colocar um número fixo de valores e o laço terminaria ao receber um valor vazio e dava o resultado final, foi removido também o `if` inicial porque não havia a necessidade dele existir.

O novo código ficou assim:

```
menor = "Nenhum"
media = "Nenhuma"
maior = "Nenhum"
qtdNumeros = 0
valor_valido = False
while valor_valido == False:
    try:
        entrada = input()
        menor = media = maior = soma = float(entrada)
        qtdNumeros = qtdNumeros + 1
        valor_valido = True
    except:
        print("Insira um valor valido!")
while entrada != '':
    entrada = input()
    try:
        valor = float(entrada)
        qtdNumeros = qtdNumeros + 1
        soma += valor
        if valor < menor:
            menor = valor
        elif valor > maior:
            maior = valor
        media = soma / qtdNumeros
    except:
        if entrada != '':
            print("Insira um valor valido!!")
print("Menor Lido:", menor)
print("Média dos Lidos:", media)
print("Maior Lido:", maior)
```