# Acessar um valor na condição de um if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Tem algum jeito de acessar um valor passado na condição de um `if`? Por exemplo:

```
a = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
b = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))

if((a-b) > 0):
    print(f'O numero {(a-b)} é maior que Zero')
```

Em vez de ter que repetir o `(a-b)` dentro do `print`, é possível apenas chamar algum método mágico que puxe a informação da condição criada na linha de cima?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No **Python 3.8** você poderá utilizar a [*assignment expression*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/5878):

```py
a = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
b = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))

if (result := (a-b)) > 0:
    print(f'O numero {result} é maior que Zero')
```

A variável `result` receberá o resultado de `(a-b)` e o valor desta variável será comparado com 0. Desta forma, você poderá utilizar a variável dentro do `if` normalmente.

Importante notar a presença dos parênteses, porque de outra forma você não teria o valor esperado:

```py
if result := (a-b) > 0:
    print(f'O numero {result} é maior que Zero')
```

Neste caso `result` receberia o resultado da comparação, um booleano, indicando se `(a-b)` é maior que zero.

Comment: Ganhou meu +1 por lembrar que isso vai existir... Mas sempre que vejo essa PEP penso que a linguagem vai virar PHPython

Comment: @fernandosavio isso dependerá apenas dos desenvolvedores, no uso moderado. Esse exemplo mesmo é bastante forçado e não tem vantagens sobre [criar uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414123/5878). Particularmente até prefiro a variável aqui por ficar mais legível, mas há casos que a *assignment expression* irá ajudar bastante.

Comment: Reli a PEP agora e, na minha opinião, vai ajudar no máximo em 5% dos casos. Só que o código vai ficar menos legível... Até achei estranho aprovarem uma PEP que parece quebrar o Zen of Python...

Comment: Acho que meu maior medo não é a _feature_, e sim o que as pessoas farão com ela... hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio A ideia é justamente suprir os 5%... Coisas como `while chunk := file.read(8192)` eu acho que ficarão bem mais legíveis e evitarão ter que iniciar a variável com um valor "aleatório", fazer uma pré-condição do `while` que inicialmente não fará sentido e somente dentro do laço atribuir o valor real à variável.

Comment: É verdade, só confirma meu último comentário... Estou assustado com a "criatividade" que as pessoas usarão para criar códigos absurdos. uaheuaheuah

Answer (score 6):

Tem, criando uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), é exatamente para isto que este mecanismo foi criado. Algumas pessoas criam onde não deve, aí é um caso que deve. Variáveis servem para guardar valores para usar posteriormente. Continuando usar nomes ruins para as variáveis serias assim:

```
a = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
b = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))
c = a - b
if c > 0:
    print(f'O numero {c} é maior que Zero')
```

Veja funcionando [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Variablepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Variable.py).

Se quer alguma coisa mais mágica que isto, não tem e não faz sentido ter.

Answer (score 0):

Use um `.format`:

```
a = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
b = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))
c = a-b
if(c > 0):
    print('O numero {} é maior que Zero'.format(c))
```

Comment: Neste caso, é mais indicado manter a *f-string*, como ele fez, do que usar o `format`. Falei disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878), se tiver interesse.