# Otimizar código em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz o código abaixo mas tenho a sensação de que ele pode ser melhorado e que talvez eu esteja dando volta demais nele.

É um código em que eu tenho uma entrada de texto e caso ela não seja escrita com todas as letras em maiúsculas eu peço para a pessoa escrever novamente, caso esteja correto ele retorna `'Texto correto.'`

```
n = input('Digite o texto todo em maiúscula: ')
res = n.isupper()

while res != True:
  n = input('Texto errado, digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
  res= n.isupper()
  continue

if res == True:

  print('Texto correto!')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não chega a ser uma otimização só refatorei o seu código o deixando menos prolixo.

```
n = input('Digite o texto todo em maiúscula: ')
while not n.isupper():
  n = input('Texto errado, digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
print('Texto correto!')
```

Código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FortunateThistleVendors)

Answer (score 6):

As duas respostas deram códigos certos, mas eu vou dar minha versão porque eu odeio quando ele viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), mesmo em código pequeno porque depois a pessoa aprende fazer sempre assim, então sem repetir partes relevante e acho que seria o "mais otimizado" que dá para fazer sem ficar ilegível ou fazer alguma maluquice:

```
while True:
    n = input('Digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
    if n.isupper():
        print('Texto correto')
        break
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tuQNAJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhileUpperpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/WhileUpper.py).

Ele não diz que está errado, mas há correntes que indicam que isso nem é bom pra UX, pra que dizer que houve erro sem necessidade, mas se quiser fazer isso mesmo:

```
while True:
    n = input('Digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
    if n.isupper():
        print('Texto correto')
        break
    else:
        print('Texto errado')
```

Já não parece tão simples, mas pelo menos não tem dois códigos fazendo a mesma coisa (que em exemplo assim não é complicado, mas já vai aprendendo evitar esse tip ode coisa).

Answer (score 5):

Dá para fazer assim:

```
n = input('Digite o texto todo em maiúscula: ')
while True:
    if n.isupper():
        print('Texto correto')
        break
    else:
        n = input('Texto errado, digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
```

`while True` cria um *loop* infinito, que só é interrompido pelo `break` - que por sua vez, só acontece se `n.isupper()` retornar `True`. Ou seja, se `n.isupper()` for `True`, ele imprime a mensagem e sai do `while`.

Repare que se um valor é booleano (como é o retorno de [`isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)), não precisa compará-lo com `True` ou `False`, basta só colocá-lo diretamente como condição do `if`.

No seu caso, `if res != True` poderia ser escrito como `if not res`, assim como `if res == True` pode ser simplesmente `if res`, mas na verdade essa variável `res` nem é necessária.

Se `n.isupper` retornar `False`, ele cai no `else` e pede que digite novamente o texto.

---

Só lembrando que `isupper` verifica se todos os chamados [*cased characteres*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id15) da string são maiúsculos, e que deve haver pelo menos um destes na string.

No caso, *cased characters* são aqueles que pertencem às categorias Unicode "[Letter, Uppercase](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)", "[Letter, Lowercase](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)" e "[Letter, Titlecase](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm)". Mas isso não significa que a string só contém esses caracteres. Por exemplo, se a string for `"1A"` ou `"A, B"`, então `isupper` também retorna `True` (o dígito "1", a vírgula e o espaço não são *cased characters*, por isso não são verificados).

Answer (score 5):

Uma one-liner para você:

```
f = lambda: input('Digite em maiúsculo: ').isupper() and 'Texto Correto!' or f()
```

Para executar:

```
f()
```

Answer (score 2):

A partir da versão 3.8 do Python você pode utilizar a [*assignment expression*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324860/5878):

```py
while not (texto := input('Digite um texto todo em maiúsculas: ')).isupper():
    print('Erro! Por favor, digite o texto com todas as letras maiúsculas')

print(f'Agora sim, você digitou: {texto}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei uma maneira mais leve e simples, reduzindo o número de variáveis e colocando o while em uma só linha só:

```
n=input(f'Digite o texto todo em maiúscula: ')
while not n.isupper(): n=input(f'Texto errado, digite tudo em maiúscula: ')
print(f'Texto correto!')
```

Eu coloquei o f no print para usar a memória flash (para não pesar na RAM) e usei o estado booleano de n em maiúscula diretamente no while.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor esse detalhe de usar o prefixo `f` para usar memória flash e não RAM? Pois o prefixo `f` define que a string poderá ser interpolada, por que ela impacta na memória que será utilizada?

Comment: Quando você imprime uma string, ela vai para a memória RAM para ser impressa. Porém, quando você coloca o f na frente da cadeia de caracteres, ela deixa de ir para a RAM e vai para a memória flash (mais rápida) para, posteriormente, ser impressa na tela. E é por isso que o código fica mais rápido quando você coloca o f na frente da string no print !!!

Comment: Mas qual é a relação das f-strings com a memória flash? Onde leu que isso acontece? Tem o link da documentação que afirma isso?

Comment: Cara, eu vi numa videoaula há uns 2 ou 3 anos, quando eu programava mais em Arduino... Aí, quando eu fui aprender Python, também podia usar isso! Eu não sei por quê, mas funciona!!!

Comment: No Python não funciona assim. O prefixo f é para informar ao interpretador que a string será interpolada. Não tem ligação com a memória utilizada.