# Recursão para Inversão de Lista em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, recursão

Estou tentando criar uma função recursiva que inverta a ordem de uma determinada lista. Como sou iniciante, acredito que esteja cometendo erros durante a construção da função.

```
    def inverter(lista, size):
        clone = []
        if size == 0:
            clone = lista
            return clone
        else:
            inverter(lista, size-1)
            clone.append(lista[size])
            return clone

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = len(l) - 1
#[5]
```

Ao printar o `size`, percebi que ele não se altera durante a execução, retornando assim apenas o ultimo elemento da lista original, vide código acima. Realmente fiquei sem saída aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*Só lembrando que recursão não é a melhor maneira de inverter uma lista, e ao longo da resposta entenderemos os motivos.*</sup>

---

A ideia básica de [recursão](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) é você resolver um problema resolvendo instâncias menores do mesmo problema e combinando os resultados (exceto se for [recursão em cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/112052), que não precisa combinar nada). No caso de inverter uma lista, o raciocínio seria:

1. pegar o último elemento da lista e colocá-lo no início
2. juntar isso com o inverso do restante da lista

   - para inverter o restante da lista, pegue do primeiro ao penúltimo elemento e volte ao primeiro passo

Existem alguns casos básicos nos quais não é preciso do passo 1 e nem do 2: quando a lista for vazia, por exemplo.

Traduzindo isso para código, fica assim:

```
def inverter(lista):
    if not lista: # lista vazia, retorna ela mesma
        return lista
    return lista[-1:] + inverter(lista[:-1])

lista = inverter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(lista) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Primeiro eu testo se a lista é vazia, com `if not lista` - isso funciona porque [uma lista vazia é considerada um valor falso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Então se a lista for vazia, eu retorno a própria lista, pois não há o que inverter.

Se a lista não for vazia, eu faço o passo 2 descrito acima. No caso, eu usei a sintaxe de [*slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295) para construir sub-listas:

- `lista[-1:]` constrói outra lista contendo apenas o último elemento de `lista`
- `lista[:-1]` constrói outra lista contendo do primeiro ao penúltimo elemento de `lista`

Sendo assim, eu pego o último elemento da lista e junto com o inverso do restante da lista.

---

Para exemplificar, suponha que eu chame `inverter([1, 2])`:

- a lista `[1, 2]` não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
- `lista[-1:]` retorna `[2]`, e é concatenada com o resultado de `inverter(lista[:-1])`

  - como `lista[:-1]` retorna `[1]`, é feita uma chamada recursiva para `inverter([1])`
  - a lista `[1]` não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
  - `lista[-1:]` retorna `[1]`, e é concatenada com o resultado de `inverter(lista[:-1])`

    - como `lista[:-1]` retorna `[]`, é feita outra chamada recursiva para `inverter([])`
    - a lista `[]` é vazia, retorna ela mesma
  - `[1]` é concatenada com uma lista vazia, o resultado é `[1]`
- `[2]` é concatenada com `[1]`, o resultado é `[2, 1]`

Repare que são criadas várias sub-listas, o que torna esse algoritmo bem ineficiente. Outro detalhe é que se a lista for muito grande, isso [pode causar um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) (e [nem precisa ser uma lista tão grande assim](https://ideone.com/EcXZgy)).

---

Até dá para eliminar a última chamada recursiva, testando se a lista tem um elemento (pois neste caso não precisa inverter também, basta retornar a própria lista):

```
def inverter(lista):
    if len(lista) <= 1: # lista vazia ou com um elemento, retorna ela mesma
        return lista
    return lista[-1:] + inverter(lista[:-1])
```

Mas ainda sim temos os problemas de criar várias sub-listas e [poder ter estouro de pilha](https://ideone.com/IpO45n) quando a lista é suficientemente grande.

Mas repare que em nenhum dos casos eu preciso passar o tamanho da lista como parâmetro da função. Ele não é necessário, e mesmo que fosse, você precisaria testar se ele está na faixa de valores correta para que não ocorra um [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).

---

Um detalhe do algoritmo acima é que ele retorna **outra** lista, contendo os elementos invertidos. Mas se quiser alterar os elementos da própria lista, basta fazer:

```
def inverter(lista, first=0, last=-1):
    if first >= len(lista) / 2:
        return
    lista[first], lista[last] = lista[last], lista[first]
    inverter(lista, first + 1, last - 1)

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
inverter(lista)
print(lista) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

A ideia é trocar o primeiro elemento de lugar com o último, depois o segundo com o penúltimo, e assim por diante, até chegar ao meio da lista (`len(lista) / 2`). Aqui não temos o problema de criar várias sub-listas, mas ainda há o [problema do estouro de pilha](https://ideone.com/CIvjjF).

Uma curiosidade deste algoritmo é que dá para escolher os índices a partir dos quais ocorrerá a inversão:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inverter(lista, 2, -3)
print(lista) # [1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 10]
```

Ou ainda:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inverter(lista, 2)
print(lista) # 1, 2, 10, 9, 8, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3]
```

Se o segundo e terceiro parâmetros não forem passados, a função assume que a inversão será feita do primeiro elemento (índice `0`) ao último (índice `-1`).

---

Enfim, apesar de ser possível, recursão não é a melhor solução para inverter uma lista. Para ver formas melhores, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192304/112052).

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Após ler seu comentário e testar, consegui fazer o código funcionar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Um primeiro problema do seu código é que o `clone` será sempre resetado a cada execução porque dentro da função existe a linha `clone = []`. Dessa forma, todos appends que você fez serão apagados. Para corrigir isto, eu criei uma função mais externa para inicializar uma única vez a lista `clone`.

Um outro problema é na condicional `if size == 0`. Lembre-se que no Python, os elementos começam a partir de 0. Então se você quiser criar uma condicional para parar ao chegar no último elemento, você deverá substituir 0 por -1.

Já no bloco else, você colocou a chamada da função `inverter` antes do `clone.append`. Você deveria fazer o contrário para que o elemento de maior index fosse acrescentado à lista `clone` e depois disso ser acrescentado o de menor index.

Veja esse código abaixo que eu fiz (Funciona):

```
def inverter(lista):
    clone = []

    def adiciona(lista, index):

        # Enquanto não chegar no último elemento, o index receberá o 
        # valor dele -1 e o elemento do index atual será adicionado à lista clone.

        if index > -1:
            clone.append(lista[index])
            adiciona(lista, index-1)

    # Adiciona à lista clone os elementos da lista original só que invertido.        
    adiciona(lista,len(lista)-1)
    return clone

lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista = inverter(lista)

print(lista) # A saída é [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Agradeço Jean, realmente ajudou bastante e esclareceu algumas dúvidas!

Comment: @zangado Vc chegou a testar o código acima? Ele nem sequer funciona: https://ideone.com/Ibzwi2

Comment: @hkotsubo o código de fato não funciona, o que me ajudou foram as pontuações e explicações que ele fez. Acredito que o código tenha sido uma ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Funciona sim pessoal e sim @hkotsubo, eu testei o código. O problema é que quando eu escrevi a resposta, eu troquei o nome da função diversas vezes para ficar bonito e esqueci de trocar o nome da função na chamada. Já corrigi o código na resposta. Peço perdão a todos, e se clicou em "Essa resposta não é útil" por causa do código, peço para que reavaliem a minha resposta.